# Cannot vote to migrate questions on app

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, android-app

On SuperUser, I found a question that belonged on another site: the question and answer were good, but it was off topic. I tried clicking **Close** --> **Off topic** --> **This belongs on another SE site** --> Choose the site (**Webmasters**), and then the menu disappears! The question is still there, and it says "`This error has been logged`" in a red bar at the top of the screen. If I follow the same process but chose to Flag, then Close, it happens then as well.

Version 0.1.68 and 0.1.70

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest deploy of the API should have fixed this error.